# Laravel DB connection problem with Apache

Tags: mysql, laravel, apache2

Error:

```
Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'montemar.users' doesn't exist
```

What is the problem?

`montemar` database exists but that table has an error (LOCKED TABLE). I don't know what is that. I can't perform queries or export the database.

for that solution I create a new database (montemar2), I changed my `.env` file,
but the project keeps querying the `montemar` database.

- I have reset the apache server (`$ systemctl apache restart`)
- I have disabled the site with `a2dissite`
- I have reset mysql server
- I have cleared the laravel cache

Nothing works.

What would be the possible solutions for the project to consult the `montemar2` database?

> I think it could be a cache issue in Apache. I would like to clean it if it exists and is possible

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if is the first time that you install the project but do you make the migration?

`php artisan make:migration`

how do you have this configuration?

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=yourdatabase
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Comment: The problem is that I change the `.env` file and it doesn't seem to affect the project

Comment: may be you have `.env.local`?

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco the project is in production, but the DB has an error. I have changed DB_DATABASE to `montemar2 ` in .env but the application continues to connect to the `montemar` database

Comment: @Franklin'jGil'z , Can you clear the cache and try? Here is the command - `php artisan config:clear`